# Change the name from VLI PRODUCT STRING

Tags: ssd

I recently bought an ssd m2 drive and an enclosure. After some formating the drive works just fine, but on some devices the name shows as 'VLI PRODUCT STRING' even though during formating it has been changed. I'm using mainly osx. Did any one encounter this problem? Does anyone know how to change it?

Thanks for the responses ;)

Comment: What's the reason you want to change it? It's it merely cosmetic or is it causing an actual problem?

Comment: not OP but I have the same problem too. It's just merely cosmetic for me :)

Comment: "name shows as 'VLI PRODUCT STRING' even though during formating it has been changed" - what does this mean exactly? you mean you set a *volume* label?

Comment: I vote close, in general you're not able to change hardware product ID's.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a M.2 enclosure but a similar SATA enclosure. The message you're seeing is because the manufacturer (Neckteck in my case), bought the USB to SATA controller off VIA Labs Inc. and didn't bother to customize the vendor name.

As mentioned in [this SE answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/116963) the `USB_DEVICE_PRODUCT_NAME` is still set to the default provided by VIA labs. This can be changed via any tools that VIA labs offers to customize the controller and I found out the chip used in my enclosure [has an SPI interface to reprogram the controller](https://www.via-labs.com/product_show.php?id=68). How to actually reprogram that is beyond the scope of my knowledge.

Comment: In effect it can not be changed by us consumers nor is intended to be, just like you can not change the product ID for you printer, the name some random device.